# How to create folder with . character in it name (windows server 2012)?

Tags: window, ssl-certificate

I need to create folder such as  **/.well-known/pki-validation/** in drive **c** .I have a **VPS** and for verify SSL certification must create folder with **.well-known** name and inside it folder with **pki-validation** name.

how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should accomplish your objective:

- First, via command line, change the working directory to your `c:` drive:

  ```
  cd c:
  ```
- Second, staying on the command line, create the proper directory using something similar to the following:

  ```
  mkdir .well-known/pki-validation
  ```

I am assuming this is for a domain ownership verification challenge. To be clear, the general proper path for these kinds of challenges is the document root (wherever your website files live) which is typically not `c:`.